# Como recuperar meu acesso adm no WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Perdi o acesso admin no WP, inclusive de maneira inesperada e sem correlação com algo específico.

Tentei resolver alterando os plugins, desativei e reativei todos eles. Renomeei a pasta de "plugins" para "plugins.velho." dentro da pasta wp-content e também não tive êxito.

Estou para ver se o local que hospeda alterou o servidor, essa é minha última opção. Caso não funcione, não sei se há mais alguma coisa que eu possa fazer. Alguém saberia por acaso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qual o erro retorna?
você pode ativar o WP_DEBUG no arquivo wp-config.php para visualizar o erro,verifique também o arquivo .htaccess

Comment: Não retornava erro específico, no painel do wordpress só não é mais possível alterar algumas coisas como adicionar plugins e alterar o tema.

Todas as opções que encontrei/testei p resolução da perda de acesso admin WP:
- Conferir se os usuários eram administradores>Checado. [1]
- Companhia pode ter alterado o acesso ao plugin e tema. [1]
- Verificar se o WP é versão .com ou .org>Checado.[1]
- Desativei os plugins de forma mais correta >Log out>DevTools>Applications>Clear Site Data>Login> Sem resultado. Reativei os plugins. [2]

Comment: - Ativar o debugging mode no WP. Dentro do wp-config.php>definir a cte por meio do comando "define('WP_DEBUG', true);" porém, o ideal é ter um backup completo do site antes de alterar os dados dessa pasta wp-config.php então eu não tentei porque preciso verificar existência de backup. [3][4][5]
- Adicionar plugins de debug no site.>Impossível[4]
- Ver se o host mudou o servidor. Inclusive, acho que também é necessário mudar o código dessa mesma pasta wp-config.php. [6]

Comment: - Checar como está definido o "DISALLOW_FILE_MODS" no wp-config.php.>Não está definido, e não precisa setar ele. O comando desabilita instalações e updates de temas e plugins. [6]
- Verificar nas configurações o wp-criticalcss. --Tô com dúvida sobre essa sugestão. Procurei essa pasta tanto pelos diretórios quanto pela ferramenta de busca do cpanel e não encontrei. [7]
- E por último sua sugestão de agora para verificar o arquivo .htaccess.

Fica aí pra quem precisar tb, de repente.

Comment: Fontes:
[1]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMv--0FODCA
[2]https://docs.presscustomizr.com/article/199-wordpress-admin-dashboard-not-displaying-properly
[3]https://www.canalwp.com/guia-do-iniciante/como-editar-o-arquivo-wp-config-php-no-wordpress/
[4]https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress
[5]https://blog.apiki.com/2015/06/08/a-trilogia-para-um-debug-seguro-e-eficaz-no-wordpress/
[6]https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php
[7]https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-settings-options-not-appearing-in-wp-admin-plugins-php/